# Initiate "adb" install, start, shell tap commands on all connected devices

Tags: android, shell, automation, adb, touch

I have this bash script function calling for automatize some installation and setup the app.

**How can I issue command on all connected devices. Not one by one?**

```
adb "$x" install xxxx.apk;
adb "$x" shell am start -n $package/$activity
adb "$x" shell tap <x> <y>
```

Here is the the working script (but it goes one by one device):

```
function install(){
    a=$(adb devices | cut -f1 | cut -f1 -d\ );
    for x in $a;
    do 
        if [ "$x" == "List" ]; 
            then continue; 
        fi; 
    
        adb -s "$x" install xxxx.apk;
    
        echo 'Launching application on device....';
        package='com.xxxx'
        activity='com.xxxx.MainFrm'
        adb $x shell am start -n $package/$activity
    
        adb $x shell input keyevent 26;
        sleep 3
        adb $x shell input tap 198 393;
        sleep 1
        adb $x shell input swipe 198 390 198 80 1500;
        sleep 2
        adb $x shell input tap 198 300;
    done
}
```

Comment: Check GNU Parallel - https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel.html#synopsis

Comment: This is interesting.. I will give it a try.